# How to solve "Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" Am I missing a DLL file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm doing some testing which outputs the full result set into script task (display messagebox) from `Execute SQL Task` using `Foreach loop Container`. but running into DTS `Script task`: runtime error.

*Error Message box*

[image: Error Message Box]

Am I missing some sort of DLL file?

*Script*

[image: Script]

*Control flow*

[image: Control FLow]

Comment: Its the "USER" in referencing your variable in the script, that's case sensitive.   Should be "User::FinalTieOut" and not "USER::FinalTieOut"

Comment: It looks like the issue was solved before i have posted my answer :) i haven't read the comments before. Anyway just read the first part of my answer to be able to detect the real exception next time. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

## Error message

> exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Is a general error message that is shown when an exception is thrown by the script code. To read the main error message you can add a try catch clause into your code and use `Dts.FireError()` method to throw the real exception.

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::FinalTieOut"].Value.ToString();
        Messagebox.Show(strMessage);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0,"An error occured", ex.Message,String.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

## Variables names

Based on [Using Variables in the Script Task - official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017):

> You add existing variables to the ReadOnlyVariables and ReadWriteVariables lists in the Script Task Editor to make them available to the custom script. **Keep in mind that variable names are case-sensitive**. Within the script, you access variables of both types through the Variables property of the Dts object. Use the Value property to read from and write to individual variables. The Script task transparently manages locking as the script reads and modifies the values of variables.

**Just change `USER::FinalTieOut` to `User::FinalTieOut` and it will solves the issue.**